# Manipulate function arguments of a variadic function template

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a pair of `begin()`/`end()` methods declared as follows:

```
template <typename... Ts>
Iterator begin(Ts... indices) const;

template <typename... Ts>
Iterator end(Ts... indices) const;
```

Logically, `end()` can be implemented in terms of `begin()`. Specifically, `end(x, y, ..., z)` is equivalent to `begin(x, y, ..., z + 1)`. So, is there a clean way to turn `x, y, ..., z` into `x, y, ..., z + 1` using `indices`, so that I can implement `end()` like

```
template <typename... Ts>
Iterator end(Ts... indices) const {
  return begin(whatever to do with indices...);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <std::size_t...Is,class... Ts>
Iterator end_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>,Ts... indices) const{
  auto tup=std::tie(indices...);
  return begin(std::get<Is>(tup)..., std::get<sizeof...(Ts)-1>(tup)+1);
}
template <class... Ts>
Iterator end(Ts... indices) const{
  return end_impl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)-1>{}, indices...);
}
```

Just add some perfect forwarding and privacy.

Uses C++14 but relatively easy to implement parts.

Comment: I might have just done `indices + (Is == sizeof...(Is) - 1 ? 0 : 1) ...` (and use `index_sequence_for<Ts...>` accordingly in `end`), but that's more a matter of style.

Comment: No need for perfect forwarding, cause `Ts...` would all be simple integer types. The solution rocks!

Comment: @T.C. I'm more in favor of your solution where the arguments don't go through an `std::tuple`.

Comment: @T.C. It should be `indices + (Is == sizeof...(Is) - 1 ? 1 : 0) ...`, by the way.

Comment: @Lingxi Right. That's what I get for not running it :/